# On a topic on MO concerning the category of topological spaces and open maps

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I was reading the following question on MO:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117174/category-of-topological-spaces-with-open-or-closed-maps

I'm not convinced about the argument within the comments according to which cartesian product and projections cannot be used to construct the product in the category $Top_{open}$. As a matter of fact, let $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(X,\tau_2)$ two topological spaces with the same underlying set. Let moreover $(X,\tau)$ a third topological space with the same property. The identity map is a morphism from $(X,\tau)$ to the other two spaces when $\tau \subseteq \tau_1 \cap \tau_2$. Consider the cartesian product $X \times X$ and the topology generated by the collection:

$$
\{Y \subseteq X \times X: \, \pi_1(Y) \in \tau_1 \,\, \textrm{and} \,\, \pi_2(Y) \in \tau_2\}
$$

In this case, the usual set-theoretic projections $\pi_1,\pi_2$ from the product might not be open maps. In fact, because the previous set is a subbase of a topology which is finer of the usual product topology (correct?), and in general noboy ensures that $\pi_1(\bigcup (A \cap B))=\bigcup (\pi_1(A) \cap \pi_1(B))$ (correct?). Therefore, the real problem is at such a level.

Anyway, assume for a moment that $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are open maps. It seems that the authors of the comments make such an assumption. So, let us assume it (even if it is probably false!) I want only to show that one of the comments (namely that starting by "If you're asking why doesn't the usual cartesian product with the usual projections give you cartesian products with respect to open maps, consider this example.") is wrong.

In this case, in fact, $(X \times X,\overline{\tau})$, where $\overline{\tau}$ is the topology generated by the previous collection of subsets, does satisfy the universal property, also for the diagonal map. Take indeed any element $A \in \tau$, then $\pi_1(h(A))=A$ and $\pi_2(h(A))=A$, which both belong to $\tau_1 \cap \tau_2$. So, in the assumption that the problem of openness of the projections does not occur, the comment provided in the post of MO seems to be false. Is my argument correct?

Comment: The comment is referring to $X\times X$ equipped with its usual product topology, not some other topology.